# Webpack dev server and css modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I can make ***css modules*** to work, but not in the hot-reload.

When first loaded, the style appears the way it should:

[image: Class names with css modules]

But after making changes to the css file it breaks, and a full reload is needed:

[image: Hot reload not working for css modules]

I'm using the css modules as shown below:

[image: css import]

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const pack = {
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/app/index.js'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/app/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /src\/app/,
        loaders: [
          'style?sourceMap',
          'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        include: /src\/app/,
        loader: 'babel',
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = pack;
```

**webpack.development.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const pack = require('./webpack.config');

pack.entry.unshift('react-hot-loader/patch');
pack.entry.unshift('webpack/hot/only-dev-server');
pack.entry.unshift('webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000');

pack.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
pack.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
}));

module.exports = pack;
```

As I have noticed, the css class that it tries to fetch in the component stills the same, shouldn't a new hash be generated for each file change/reload?

Comment: Did you add a `module.accept()` statement in your sources?

Comment: No... I solved it changing `pack.entry.unshift('webpack/hot/only-dev-server');` to `pack.entry.unshift('webpack/hot/dev-server');`. It refreshed everything but updates the css as expected.

Comment: That might explain why you're getting a full refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The HMR API exposes a small runtime, which is accessed through `module.hot`, that you'll have to interact with in order to consolidate the updates and apply changes to the document's state, otherwise you're left with something that is akin to a live reload server as you're not opting into HMR.

You have correctly stated yourself that each update should provide with you with a new set of class names, as long as there is a `[hash]` variant used to construct the name, so what's needed it to invalidate the modules that reference the JS module with the export and re-apply the class names.

There is an example provided in the [new documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/), for Webpack 2, which currently has a release candidate available under the `beta` distribution tag, which you can install via `npm i webpack@beta`. I would recommend that you migrate over immediately and switch to `react-hot-loader` 3, available under the `next` distribution tag, which you can install via `npm i react-hot-loader@next`, both of which should provide a much better experience. However, you're welcome to use your existing versions.

For HMR to work, you'll need to have a module that requires the root component of your React component tree and render it under RHL's container. This can be performed in a function that has the signature `render(root)`, which you will subsequently call each time one of the modules that is part of your root's module's dependency graph:
    // ./src/index.js
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

```
import {AppContainer} from 'react-hot-loader';

import App from './components/app';

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

render(App);

// Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
  // Accept updates for all modules that are part of our root app component's
  // module's dependency graph.
  module.hot.accept('./components/app', () => {
    // Re-render, allowing `react-hot-loaders` behavior to kick in,
    // invalidating the whole React element tree.
    render(App)

    // If you are not using native ES6 export syntax, you will have to
    // re-require the export again. 

    // const NewApp = require('./components/app').default
    // render(NewApp)
  });
}
```